# Sample space of a transformation of a random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables

> If $X$ is a random variable with cdf $F_{X}(x)$, then any function of $X$, say $g(X)$, is also a random variable. Often $g(X)$ is of interest itself and we write $Y=g(X)$ to denote the new random variable $g(X)$. Since $Y$ is a function of $X$, we can describe the probabilistic behavior of $Y$ in terms of that of $X$. That is, for any set $A$,
> $$
> P(Y \in A)=P(g(X) \in A),
> $$
> showing that the distribution of $Y$ depends on the functions $F_{X}$ and $g$. Depending on the choice of $g$, it is sometimes possible to obtain a tractable expression for this probability.
>
> Formally, if we write $y=g(x)$, the function $g(x)$ defines a mapping from the original sample space of $X, \mathcal{X}$, to a new sample space, $\mathcal{Y}$, the sample space of the random variable $Y$. That is,
> $$
> g(x): \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}
> $$

Why is the sample space of $Y$ different from the sample space of $X$? Wouldn't they both have the same sample space (domain) of $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}=\Omega$?

Comment: There is indeed only one sample space $\Omega$ and we have random variables $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  But $\mathcal{X}=\{X(\omega): \omega \in \Omega\}$ and $\mathcal{Y}=\{Y(\omega) : \omega \in \Omega\}$, these sets can be different, and some people might call $\mathcal{X}$ the "sample space relative to $X$" and $\mathcal{Y}$ the "sample space relative to $Y$.

Comment: @Michael Ah there is a distinction between the "sample space of values a random variable can take" and the "sample space of the probability space"?

Comment: @SamKirkiles Yes. Also, $\Omega$ is usually called a "measurable space", or the "underlying set of a probability space", instead of "sample space".

Comment: Yes. I agree that is confusing terminology. As a minor technical detail, the spirit of the above text is correct to use "any" function $g$ and "any" set $A$, but technically if $X$ is a random variable then $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ must be a Borel measurable function to ensure $g(X)$ is a random variable, and $A$ must be a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to ensure $P[Y\in A]$ is well defined.

Comment: @BrianChao : For the probability triplet $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, I think most people would call $\Omega$ the sample space (at least, I would).  The pair $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space (a nonempty set together with a sigma algebra on that set).

Comment: @Michael Yes thanks for clarifying I assumed this was implicitly assumed as this text does not reference measure theory.

Comment: Brian's comment actually reminds me though that some people would call  $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ the "range" of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, so $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$.  Now some people use "range" as synonymous with "image" and others do not (they might allow "range" to be a superset of image).  So there is plenty of room for confusion between the terminology used by different textbooks. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize my above comments:

Indeed there is only one sample space $\Omega$, and we have random variables:
\begin{align}
X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
\end{align}
The set $\Omega$ is the (common) domain of the functions $X, Y$, the set $\mathbb{R}$ is the (common) target set of the functions $X,Y$. The sets $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{Y}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ can be used to either refer to the *images* or the *ranges* of the random variables.  The set $\mathcal{X}$ is sometimes called the "sample space relative to the random variable $X$" while the set $\mathcal{Y}$ is sometimes called the "sample space relative to the random variable $Y$."
I agree the terminology can be confusing.  One confusing thing is that some textbooks treat "image" and "range" as synonymns while others treat "range" and "target set" as synonymns (whereas I think nobody treats "image" and "target set" as synonymns).

I like to define the *images* by the set of values **that can actually be achieved**:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{X} = \{X(\omega) : \omega \in \Omega\} \\
\mathcal{Y} = \{Y(\omega) : \omega \in \Omega\}
\end{align}
Since $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{Y}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ it makes sense to write
\begin{align}
X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathcal{X}\\
Y:\Omega\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}
\end{align}
so that $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ can also be viewed as the (potentially different) target sets for $X$ and $Y$.

---

Formally, a **measurable space** is a pair $(\Gamma, \mathcal{G})$ such that $\Gamma$ is a nonempty set and $\mathcal{G}$ is a sigma algebra on $\Gamma$.  For doing probability we always assume there is a **probability triplet** $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space and $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow [0,1]$ is a probability measure. Then:

1. A **random variable** is a (measurable) function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.
2. A **random element** is a (measurable) function $Z:\Omega\rightarrow \Gamma$ where $(\Gamma, \mathcal{G})$ is some given measurable space.

I put the word "measurable" in parentheses to de-emphasize it. For random variables, we use "Borel measurability" and it means that
$$\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{F} \quad \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
which holds if and only if
$$\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\} \in \mathcal{F} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Here $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.
The set of Borel measurable functions is so extensive that it includes all functions of practical use, you will never be in danger of accidentally defining a non-Borel measurable function, so basic probability classes ignore the issue of measurability.  Basic classes also usually do not treat random elements in abstract measurable spaces. However, for completeness, I note that the formal definition of "measurable" for random elements $Z:\Omega\rightarrow \Gamma$ is similar:
$$ \{\omega \in \Omega : Z(\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{F} \quad \forall B \in \mathcal{G}$$

Now another confusing point of terminology is that, while most mathematics textbooks and papers agree with the above notation regarding "random variable" versus "random element," some computer science books like to treat "random variable" and "random element" as synonymns.

Comment: Many thanks for this very detailed answer I really appreciate it